# Pie chart Vega lite : conditional label colors

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

I would like to have conditional label colors in the "fill" section for my text layer.

[Link to my pbix](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An2aQoxg76Kv6jnMWzcGS6aWvMr9?e=d4XYOf)

I have tried this but it won't work...

```
"fill": {
     "condition":{
     "test": "datum.Name = 'Other players'" ,
            "value": "black"},
     "value": "white"
  }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I want all the value labels to be filled in black except the "other players" value which I want to be filled in grey ? Thanks

Comment: For sure ! I think i have upvoted every single answers. Tell me if not !

Comment: The solution is perfect ! I think i have upvoted your solution but I must admit i struggle a little bit to find how to do so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

```
{
  "width": "container",
  "height": "container",
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {
      "field": "Points_calculation",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "stack": true
    },
    "order": {
      "field": "ORDER",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "sort": "descending"
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "Name",
      "type": "nominal",
      "sort": {
        "field": "ORDER",
        "order": "descending"
      },
      "legend": null,
      "scale": {
        "scheme": "pbiColorNominal"
      }
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "name": "******RING BACKGROUND GEN COL******",
      "mark": {
        "type": "arc",
        "outerRadius": 100
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "******RING BACKGROUND OTHER COL******",
      "mark": {
        "type": "arc",
        "outerRadius": 100,
        "fill": {
          "expr": "datum.Name =='Other players'?'grey':''"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "******Name labels******",
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "radius": 115,
        "dy": 4,
        "fill": "black",
        "align": {
          "expr": "scale('theta', datum.Points_calculation_end - datum.Points_calculation_start + datum.Points_calculation_start ) > PI  ?'right':'left'"
        }
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "Name",
          "type": "nominal"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "******Values_Labels******",
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "radius": 80,
        "fill":{"expr":"datum.Name =='Other players'?'black':'white'"}
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "Points_calculation",
          "type": "nominal"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Awsome ! thanks a lot. I get the use of expr...